# System V Semaphores - semop() in different function

Tags: c, semaphore

I created and initialized System V semaphores with `semget()` and `semctl()`  in the main function, but the `semop()` function is called in a different function. I simply passed the ids of the semaphores as parameters to that function. It looks something like this:

```
int manageProcesses(int* data, int* numProcesses, int semId, int mutex, int time)
{
    semop(mutex, &semwait, 1);
    ...
}
```

Does this work or should `semop()` be called in the same function as `semget()` and `semctl()`?

Comment: You can't mix `semget/semctl/...` with `semop`. They use _different_ mechanisms. Pick one or the other.

Comment: @CraigEstey, `semget()`, `smectl()`, and `semop()` are the three Sys V semaphore manipulation functions.  They work in concert.  Are you supposing that some of them are for POSIX semaphores?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oops, yes--my bad. I conflated them as POSIX. My only excuse is that I was mobile (and couldn't double check the definitions) and was pre-coffee ;-) I assumed that OP had tried the code and it failed, not realizing the simplicity of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this work or should `semop()` be called in the same function as `semget()` and `semctl()`?

The id of a semaphore set, as obtained from `semget()`, is a process-scoped handle on an object (the semaphore set) with kernel persistence.  Once you obtain one, you can use that anywhere in the program in conjunction with `semctl()` and / or `semop()`, until and unless you remove the semaphore set via `semctl(..., IPC_RMID)`, or some other process removes it.